# Educativo, ¿Por que no funciona este código?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Saludos,

Realizando un pequeño ejercicio de obtener un estilo css según una condición de Si o No pero no me funciona, ¿por qué?

.cs

```
protected void btn_tester(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string spanClassMail = "<span style='color:red;'>";
    if (this.cblCotSoatContacto.SelectedValue == "Si")
    {
        spanClassMail = "<span style='color:red;'>";
    }
    else
    {
        spanClassMail = "<span style='color:green;'>";
    }
    this.lblTester.Text = spanClassMail;
}
```

.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTester" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btn_tester" />
```

Comment: ¿Te indica algún error? ¿qué está fallando exactamente?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Puedes elaborar mejor tu pregunta? ¿Que exactamente es lo que quieres?

Comment: No, no me arroja ningún error, la etiqueta label pasa de ser label a nada, quyeda vacía, la falla es que no me arroja el string de `<span style='color:green;'>`

Comment: @Einer, lo que quiero es poner el valor de color rojo, según si es Si, es verde y si es No es rojo, en un texto X.

Comment: pero le estas pasando la cadena CSS al texto?

Comment: si la estoy pasando desde el .cs `<h3>¿Desea que lo contacten?" + spanClassMail +this.cblCotSoatContacto.SelectedItem + "</span></h3>"`

Comment: @Vulpex te funciono la sugerencia o intentaste otra?

Answer (score 0):

`Text` cambia el texto del `Label`. Para cambiarle el color al control `lblTester` utiliza la propiedad `ForeColor`:

```
   if (this.cblCotSoatContacto.SelectedValue == "Si")
    {
        lblTester.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        lblTester.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
```

Comment: Pues quiero obtenerlo como cadena de Texto, como quien dice en código completo para enviarlo por un `string` a otro sitio, y aunque probé el código que pusiste, igual no funciona, no cambia de color se queda en rojo.

Comment: Si selecionas No, no cambia de color?

Comment: Nope, no cambia, se queda en rojo, supondré que no está recogiendo el valor del checkbox?

Comment: Que extraño. A mi me funciona.

Comment: Cree un archivo completamente nuevo, para realizar la prueba y copie y pegue el código que necesito y funciona, pero por algún extraño motivo dentro del original no funciona, osea yo tenía la duda de que estuviera creando mal el código, que así  no se declara la variable o yo que sé. No me queda mas que revisar completamente el código haber que carajos pasa.

Comment: Que pudiste averigurar? Lo hiciste funcionar?

Comment: Solucionado cambié `"Si" por "1"` y `"No" por "0"` pues así están los `Value` del `DropDownList`, lo extraño es que funcione bien en un archivo en blanco pero no funcione en el archivo final. la linea final quedo así :`if (this.cblCotSoatContacto.SelectedValue == "0")`

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Suerte!